# Picking the smallest and biggest numbers of a list without any methods

Tags: java, algorithm

Im trying to pick from a list of 5 numbers, the biggest and the smallest numbers.
With the biggest I have no problems, either with the smallest for some cases.
But, for the smallest number I would like to adding a condition that if its zero ('0'), I wouldn't pick it, thats mean from 5 numbers I would like to pick the smallest one, that is not 0.
for example: 
1000 2000 3000 0 0 
I would like to pick the 1000.

Also, I can't use any methods, or based functions, Just If statements.

thats my code:

```
if((manufactorsPrice1<manufactorsPrice2)&&(manufactorsPrice1<manufactorsPrice3)&&(manufactorsPrice1<manufactorsPrice4)&&(manufactorsPrice1<manufactorsPrice5)){
                if(manufactorsPrice1>0){
                        smallestPrice=manufactorsPrice1;
                    }
                }else if((manufactorsPrice2<manufactorsPrice3)&&(manufactorsPrice2<manufactorsPrice4)&&(manufactorsPrice2<manufactorsPrice5)){
                    if(manufactorsPrice2>0){
                        smallestPrice=manufactorsPrice2;
                    }
                }else if((manufactorsPrice3<manufactorsPrice4)&&(manufactorsPrice3<manufactorsPrice5)){
                    if(manufactorsPrice3>0){
                        smallestPrice=manufactorsPrice3;
                    }
                }else if(manufactorsPrice4 < manufactorsPrice5){
                    if(manufactorsPrice4>0){
                        smallestPrice=manufactorsPrice4;
                    }
                }else{
                    if(manufactorsPrice5>0){
                        smallestPrice=manufactorsPrice5;
                    }}
```

Thats work fine if I could pick the 0 as the smallest, But I cannot. Please help me, How can I pick the next smallest number that is not a Zero from the list.?
thanks.

Comment: Better fit for codegolf.se.....

Comment: Avoid naming variables with numbers. When you start seeing numbers in the variable names it is time for a collection such as an array or `ArrayList`

Comment: Okay, I changed the varriables names, But this is not what prevent this from working, So if anyone have an idea, It will be great.

Comment: @etomernud the point is not to change the names, but use some type of collection so that you can loop through them and find the smallest instead of these insane if statements

Comment: I know there is way better options to do this thing, But this is my mission, I cannot use any other methods than IF and SWITCH.

Comment: The fact that you are not allowed to use collections or methods makes me uncomfortable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution which only uses an extra local variable to reduce nesting. It will find the minimum non-zero value (if it exists) or zero in the case they are all 0. It also uses fewer comparisons.

```
    ...

int min1, min2;

if (a2 == 0 || (a1 < a2 && a1 != 0))
  min1 = a1;
else
  min1 = a2;

if (a4 == 0 || (a3 < a4 && a3 != 0))
  min2 = a3;
else
  min2 = a4;

if (min1 == 0 || (min2 < min1 && min2 != 0))
   min1 = min2;

if (min1 == 0 || (a5 < min1 && a5 != 0))
  min1 = a5;

return min1;
```

Comment: @etomernud No problem. If this answered your question, hit the check at the side to mark it as accepted.

Comment: Actually, When I tried deeper to mix the numbers its not working, It works only if you type : 1 2 3 0 0 , as long as the zero's in the end, if you mix them in the start, It doesnt work, Please if you can help me further :) thanks

Comment: @etomernud Whoops, fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Solution appropriate for your teacher who only allows the use of conditionals...

```
            s=
           (s=
           (s=
           (s=
        x2!=0&&x2
    <x1?x2:x1)>x3
    &&x3!=0?x3:s)>x4
    &&x4!=0?x4:s)>x5
     &&x5!=0?x5:s;
```